# Express router going inside the same route

Tags: node.js, express

I have setup 3 different routes which have their own subroutes

```
  router.use('/items', handleItems(app, router));
  router.use('/price', handlePrice(app, router));
  router.use('/documents', handleDocuments(app, router));
```

But when i call `http://localhost:3000/api/documents/`, it is throwing error as if it is calling functions inside `/items` routes. How can this happen?

After some more debugging i noticed that call is going inside `handleItems` handler to the `/:id` route

```
function handleItems(app, router) {
  router.post('/create-one', itemController.createItem);
  router.get('/:id', itemController.getItem);
  return router;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet from your handle* functions? How's it implemented

Comment: updated the question with the snippets

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [`express.Router`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) documentation.

In your example you have:

```
function handleItems(app, router) {
  router.post('/create-one', itemController.createItem);
  router.get('/:id', itemController.getItem);
  return router;
}
```

The first parameter is not used, and the second parameter is your `router` object, so basically, you are registering your routes in the same object and you will end up with something like

```
/items
/create-one
/:id
/price
```

What you are looking for is something like:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use("/items", handleItems(Router()));
app.use("/documents", handleDocuments(Router()));

function handleItems(r) {
  r.get("/tada", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: `Tada` }));
  r.get("/:name", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: `Hello ${req.params.name}` }));
  return r;
}

function handleDocuments(r) {
  r.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Bonjour" }));
  return r;
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(" Listening"));
```

In the example above, I registered a "new router" under each path (`/items` and `/documents`)

then, I registered each of these at their root paths:

```
app.use("/items", handleItems(Router()));
```

With:

```
function handleItems(r) {
  router.post('/create-one', itemController.createItem);
  router.get('/:id', itemController.getItem);
  return r;
}
```

---

I don't know which architecture or what pattern you are using in your application, but if you are not using any you may want to use the following:

Create a `routes.js` file for each of items, price and documents. For example:

```
// items.routes.js
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

router.post('/create-one', itemController.createItem);
router.get('/:id', itemController.getItem);

module.exports = router;
```

Then in the app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// load routers
const itemsRoutes = require('./path/to/items.routes.js');
const documentsRoutes = require('./path/to/documents.routes.js');

app.use("/items", itemsRoutes);
app.use("/documents", documentsRoutes);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(" Listening"));
```

This might be a cleaner and more predictable pattern to work with in many cases

Comment: I understood the mistake. But, i am still confused about how `/items/create-one` was working fine in such case?